# Acumatica - Add additional buttons to Actions drop down to screen CT30100

Tags: erp, acumatica

I am trying to add a button to the Acumatica ERP screen CT301000 Actions drop down, I have added the button to the graph and modified the aspx to include the following in the `PXDatasource=>CallbackCommands`:

```
px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="TerminateRevenue" Visible="false" CommitChanges="True"
```

However I am unsure how to add the the button into the Actions collection.
does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Hi
I don't know which customization technique you're using, but you don't need to modify aspx page. Just use the following codes

```
public YourConstructor()
{
    action.Add(yourAction);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To create a drop-down button, you should complete the following steps:

1. Declare the following actions within the TaskTemplateMaint BLC as follows:

   ```
   public PXAction<TaskTemplate> Approve;
   [PXButton]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Approve")]
   protected virtual void approve()
   {
       TaskTemplate template = Templates.Current;
       template.IsApproved = true;
       Templates.Update(template);
   }

   public PXAction<TaskTemplate> Reject;
   [PXButton]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reject")]
   protected virtual void reject()
   {
       TaskTemplate template = Templates.Current;
       template.IsRejected = true;
       Templates.Update(template);
   }

   public PXAction<TaskTemplate> ActionsMenu;
   [PXButton]
   [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Actions")]
   protected virtual void actionsMenu()
   {
   }
   ```
2. Declare constructor for the BLC and add Approve and Reject actions as drop-down items for ActionsMenu as follows:

   ```
   public TaskTemplateMaint()
   {
       ActionsMenu.AddMenuAction(Approve);
       ActionsMenu.AddMenuAction(Reject);
       ActionsMenu.MenuAutoOpen = true;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The CT301000 screen uses the ContractMaint BLC

You can create an extension as follows in visual studio and reference the resulting dll in the web site to show the button.

```
public class ContractMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<ContractMaint>
{
    public PXSelect<Contract> pCenters;

    public PXAction<Contract> DoSomething;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Button")]
    protected void doSomething()
    {
        //do actions 
    }



}
```

this creates the button and will automatically cause it to be displayed.