# Acumatica ERP 6.0 Create Reports Dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, acumatica

I have created my custom Entry and I need to add some reports to it.
I'm trying to get Reports Dropdown like this 
[image]
But all my efforts are unsuccessful.

I have action and function like is in the Receipt Entry

```
    public PXAction<MyMasterView> report;

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reports", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select),PXButton(SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.Report)]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Report(PXAdapter adapter, [PXString(8, InputMask = "CC.CC.CC.CC"), PXStringList(new string[]{"PO649999","PO646000"}, new string[]{"Print My Report","Print Receipt"})] string reportID)
    {
        List<MyMasterView> list = adapter.Get<MyMasterView>().ToList<MyMasterView>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportID))
        {
            this.Save.Press();
            int num = 0;
            Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (MyMasterViewcurrent in list)
            {
                dictionary["PARAMETER"] = current.PARAMETER;
                num++;
            }
            if (num > 0)
            {
                throw new PXReportRequiredException(dictionary, reportID, string.Format("Report {0}", reportID));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

But as a result I'm getting the following

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can handle this.

One way is outlined in another question here:
[Acumatica - Add additional buttons to Actions drop down to screen CT30100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270909/acumatica-add-additional-buttons-to-actions-drop-down-to-screen-ct30100)

The other method is to utilize a list and control it with automation steps.

If you look at the PO Receipts screen you can see this.
1) Create your button method that takes a list of other items:

```
public PXAction<POReceipt> report;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reports", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual IEnumerable Report(PXAdapter adapter,         

    [PXString(8, InputMask = "CC.CC.CC.CC")]
    [PXStringList(new string[] { "PO646000", "PO632000", "PO622000" }, new string[] { "Purchase Receipt", Messages.ReportPOReceiptBillingDetails, Messages.ReportPOReceipAllocated })]
    string reportID)
    {
        List<POReceipt> list = adapter.Get<POReceipt>().ToList();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportID) == false)
    {
            Save.Press();
        int i = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (POReceipt doc in list)
        {

            if (reportID == "PO632000")
            {
                parameters["FinPeriodID"] = (string)Document.GetValueExt<POReceipt.finPeriodID>(doc);
                    parameters["ReceiptNbr"] = doc.ReceiptNbr;
            }
            else
            {
                    parameters["ReceiptType"] = doc.ReceiptType;
                parameters["ReceiptNbr"] = doc.ReceiptNbr;
            }
            i++;

        }
        if (i > 0)
        {
            throw new PXReportRequiredException(parameters, reportID, string.Format("Report {0}", reportID));
        }
    }
        return list;
    }
```

Notice the PXStringList that has the possible values and the descriptions.

Then you can control active/inactive state from the Automation Steps.

[image]

The step you are missing in your original question is that you still need to add these buttons from the automation steps to add them to the list.